# How do you receive slash commands in Discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I'm fairly new to Python.
I was wondering how to receive slash commands in Discord without using webhooks.
Here is my code:

```
import requests

url = "https://discord.com/api/v8/applications/#ID#/guilds/#ID#/commands"

json = {
    "name": "Help",
    "description": "List bot commands.",
    "type": 4
}

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bot #TOKEN#"
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json)
```

Basically, I would like the bot to have a help slash command and respond with a message.
I've looked through some of the docs but can't quite understand.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: There’s not even a line related to discord.py here

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński not directly, but indirectly. Maybe he has the hope we know it because we maybe also have those issues in our day

Comment: What code would you like to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you are on the right way, but with that method you will just create the help command for the guild id and not handle it. To handle a command you should use discord-py-slash-command (https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Happy coding!